# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: ssh, remote-access

When attempting to run a remote binary using `sudo` on the remote box:

```
ssh remotehost "sudo ./binary"
```

I see this error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

A simple way is to specify `-t`:

```
ssh -t remotehost "sudo ./binary"
```

From the man page:

> Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

<strike>I cannot explain exactly why this works, and there may be a better way. I'd like to hear about it if so :)</strike>

@psusi explains why this works in a comment below.

Comment: It works because `sudo` requires a tty to prompt for a password, and when specifying commands to run to `ssh`, it doesn't allocate one by default since this is normally used to run non interactive commands that may transfer binary data, which can trip up the tty.

Comment: @psusi Do you know the answer to this related question? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110841

Comment: There is also [`-tt`](https://serverfault.com/a/625695/498092), required when passing command using heredoc

Comment: This is best way. Worked for me.

Answer (score 39):

## Question:

How can I work around this?

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

## Alternate Answer

As an alternative, try:

`sudo -S ./[yourExecutable]`

This directs sudo to read the password from the standard input, stdin.

## Scenarios where this Helps

In chroot environments, these other answers may not work correctly ... perhaps because:

1. /etc/shadow vs /etc/passwd conflict not allowing the user to enter a password.
2. In a chroot-ed environment, access to tty1 can be a bit glitchy, and ctrl-alt f2 -- to tty2 is unfeasible, because it is a tty of the non-chroot-ed environment.

***For example:*** Manually installing / repairing linux or the bootloader, using a chroot environment, (such as Archlinux and arch-chroot).

Comment: I get a sudo: ./binary: command not found error when I run sudo -S ./binary, what gives?

Comment: @AjitGoel it was just an example. Replace ./binary with the command you want to run.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanx

Answer (score 6):

It fails, because `sudo` is trying to prompt on root password and there is no pseudo-tty allocated.

You've to either log-in as root or set-up the following rules in your `/etc/sudoers`
 (or: `sudo visudo`):

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then make sure that your user belongs to `admin` group (or `wheel`).

Comment: whilst this is not true (no evidence is given for this, and users in the admin group with that code in centos and ubuntu systems still get the error), it is a great tip for remoting to create groups and rules based upon those groups for escalated tasks

Answer (score 4):

You need to define terminal/application that will read the password.  There are two variants:

1. `export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass`
2. `vim /etc/sudoers`  (Defaults visiblepw)

Comment: Is it not better to use `visudo` instead of `vim /etc/sudoers` in order to avoid potentially locking yourself out of your machine due to having made an error in your edit?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I've received this error because I wasn't specifying a command that I would like to use as root in the sudoers

Something like

`/etc/sudoers.d/myuser`:

```
myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: \
    /bin/ls -la
```

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a file like "sudo_shutdown" in /etc/sudoers.d, with content:

```
# Allow admins to shutdown without pass
%adm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

This allows users which are in the adm group to shutdown without a password.

Comment: Did you intend to [edit] this to cover "no tty present"